# Find the maximum value from the latest 3 timestamps for each category

Tags: sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to write the sql query in databricks for

[image: 1]

For each distinct pair of column (A,B) what is the maximum value of column C from **last 3 recent timestamp** for that pair (A,B)

Output is

[image: 2]

```
Here you can see that for A column which contains '1' and B column conatins 'GG' specifically below are the timestamp and C column output
12:12 -> False
12:14 -> False
12:15 -> True
12:16 -> False

Here the latest 3 recent timestamps are
12:14 -> False
12:15 -> True
12:16 -> False

and the maximum of C column is "True" which comes from 12:15 timestamp
```

Comment: But the maximum of C column is "False" comes from 12:16 right? What you actually meant by maximum value.

Comment: among true and false maximum value is true

Answer (score 0):

Your DataFrame (df_1):

```
+---+----------------------------+---+-----+
|A  |Timestamp                   |B  |C    |
+---+----------------------------+---+-----+
|1  |2023-02-01T12:14:00.000+0000|GG |FALSE|
|1  |2023-02-01T12:15:00.000+0000|GG |TRUE |
|2  |2023-02-01T12:15:00.000+0000|AA |TRUE |
|1  |2023-02-01T12:16:00.000+0000|GG |FALSE|
|4  |2023-02-01T21:34:00.000+0000|GG |TRUE |
|2  |2023-02-01T21:34:00.000+0000|AA |TRUE |
|1  |2023-02-01T12:12:00.000+0000|GG |FALSE|
|2  |2023-02-01T21:38:00.000+0000|AA |FALSE|
+---+----------------------------+---+-----+
```

Importing necessary packages:

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import max, rank
```

1. Rank each record by grouping column `A` and `B` using the `Timestamp` column descendingly

```
window_spec = Window.partitionBy("A", "B").orderBy(col("Timestamp").desc())

df_2 = df_1.withColumn("rank", rank().over(window_spec))
```

2. Filter the records having rank less than 3, equivalent to top 3 and drop the rank column

```
df_3 = df_2.filter("rank <= 3").drop("rank")
```

3. Group the `A` and `B` and use the `max()` to fetch the maximum value from `C`

```
df_3.groupBy("A","B").agg(max("C").alias("C")).show()
```

***Output:***

```
+---+---+----+
|  A|  B|   C|
+---+---+----+
|  1| GG|TRUE|
|  2| AA|TRUE|
|  4| GG|TRUE|
+---+---+----+`
```

Comment: Hi arudsekaberne Thank you for the reply...
Actually i want to get the maximum value of C column only from the last 3 recent timestamp of given pair A,B

Comment: Can you show or update the desired output you want? Helps us better understanding.